# Raise an EventHandler<TEventArgs> event with a Moq instance

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the interfaces

```
public interface IBar
{

}
```

and

```
public interface IFoo
{
    event EventHandler<IBar> MyEvent;
}
```

and a class

```
public class Foobar
{
    public Foobar(IFoo foo)
    {
        foo.MyEvent += MyEventMethod;
    }

    private void MyEventMethod(object sender, IBar bar)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Now I want to unit test this brilliant piece of code using Moq 4:

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    Mock<IFoo> foo = new Mock<IFoo>();
    Mock<IBar> bar = new Mock<IBar>();

    Foobar foobar = new Foobar(foo.Object);

    foo.Raise(e => e.MyEvent += null, bar.Object);
}
```

From my understanding Foobar.MyEventMethod should be called through the raise. What happens is that I get a runtime exception that says System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountEception {"Parameter count mismatch."}.

Funny thing: when I Raise the following in the unit test:

```
foo.Raise(e => e.MyEvent += null, EventArgs.Empty, bar.Object);
```

Everything works as I want it. Can anybody explain why three arguments are needed for the call?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post a sample that compiles and includes `IBar` class? After fixing obvious compilation errors your sample works under .NET 4.0 & Moq 4.2.

Comment: Sry, just hacked it in. What a surprise it did not compile ;-) Now it should

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you use .NET 4.5 then. [Type constraint was removed from `EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15736970) which allows you to do something like this:

```
event EventHandler<IBar> MyEvent;
```

Where `IBar` is just *some interface*.

IN 4.0, with constraint restricting `TEventArgs` to be assignable to `EventArgs` type, your code wouldn't compile.

As a result of this (`IBar` not deriving from `EventArgs`), Moq doesn't consider your event as ["corresponding to Event Handler pattern"](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#events), and treats it as any other delegate:

```
// Raising a custom event which does not adhere to the EventHandler pattern
...
// Raise passing the custom arguments expected by the event delegate
mock.Raise(foo => foo.MyEvent += null, 25, true);
```

Which means you have to provide **all** parameters, including *sender*.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Really sheds some light. But I'm still missing why there are three parameters, I'd expect I'd need object sender, TEventArgs args.

Comment: @anhoppe: The first parameter is there to tell Moq *which* event to raise, `foo => foo.MyEvent += null` -- Moq will dissect this `Expression` and figure out you want `MyEvent` to be raised. The remaining ones are whatever your custom delegate requires (`object sender` and `EventArgs args`).

Answer (score 6):

The reason the first is not working because EventHandlers have 2 parameters (object sender, EventArgs args).

When you are setting up mocking

```
foo.Raise(e => e.MyEvent += null, EventArgs.Empty, bar.Object);
```

the`e => e.MyEvent += null` is an expression to tell `Moq` which event to raise,

The following 2 parameters are the 2 arguments you want to raise it with.

```
EventArgs.Empty, bar.Object
```

*Note: If memory serves me right, those should be the other way around.*

When you try to raise an event with 1 argument (`bar.Object`) `Moq` throws an exception saying that event handler requires 2 as it uses reflection to invoke it.

Your first case could be written like this:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public event EventHandler<IBar> MyEvent;

    public void OnMyEvent(IBar bar)
    {
        MyEvent(EventArgs.Empty)
    }
}
```

Which gives you a compiler error:  Delegate 'EventHandler' does not take 1 arguments

So that's why you need 2 parameters, as you would invoke it with the following:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public event EventHandler<IBar> MyEvent;

    public void OnMyEvent(IBar bar)
    {
        MyEvent(this, bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sender parameter is not required when event is done correctly. See: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#events

Comment: Thats if he uses EventHandler, not EventHandler<X>. Tbh i didnt know that it would even work if IFoo was inheriting from EventHandler, guess i learnt something new.

Comment: EventArgs.Empty was the missing part for me. Thank you.