# Why was EventArgs constraint dropped from EventHandler<TEventArgs>?

Tags: .net, events, compatibility, eventargs, generic-constraints

In .NET Framework 2.0, delegate EventHandler got its generic generalization that allowed the second argument to be not only of type EventArgs, but also of a derived type, imposing a stricter constraint on its implementations. But somewhen in .NET Framework 4, [likely in .NET Framework 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15737300/2157640), the generic constraint was removed, according to a comment I found both in [reference source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/9da503f9ef21e8d1f2905c78d4e3e5cbb3d6f85a/mscorlib/system/eventhandler.cs) and [.NET Runtime source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/2024b63acd460edeb53b2ce6984710ab51c11f2f/src/coreclr/src/mscorlib/src/System/EventHandler.cs).

```cs
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.

namespace System
{
    public delegate void EventHandler(object? sender, EventArgs e);

    public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object? sender, TEventArgs e); // Removed TEventArgs constraint post-.NET 4
}
```

But **what was the point in dropping the constraint** and thus breaking the compatibility with extant users? Or, to make this answerable even by someone outside the .NET team, what could be such a motivation?

I came across this archaic change due to SonarQube rule [S3906](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/tag/convention/RSPEC-3906), which looks like a copy of the deprecated [CA1009](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1009?view=vs-2019) and requires that the event handler's type requires EventArgs as its second argument. This is now in conflict with [CA1003](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1003), which requires the use of the generic EventArgs<TEventArgs>. I chose to suppress the issue via EditorConfig as I cannot change the quality profile in SonarQube, but I am still left wondering why this breaking change was needed in the first place.

I've seen a very similar question asked before as part of [a great question regarding EventHandler<TEventArgs> variance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54907236/2157640) and also in [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15737300/2157640) but my question was not answered there. Their question is about why the constraint is not there (current state), I am asking about why it was removed (reason for change), which feels a bit different because the reason needs to be strong enough to justify the change.

Comment: I don't get why it breaks anything: if a handler has the signature `void (object, EventArgs)` it can still be passed to the constructor of the generic `EventArgs<TEventArgs>`, the only thing that breaks is that `void (object, object)` now compiles where it did not before

Comment: I was thinking about binary compatibility and a situation when a binary calls the event handler with e.g. EventArgs.Empty and after the change to the definition of EventHandler<TEventArgs>, it is no longer guaranteed that EventArgs.Empty is a valid value. But now that I gave it a bit more thought, I cannot come up with a scenario when this backfires. :-( It's quite late here and I had a rough day, will need to think about that more in the morning.